# P (2ap,ap ²) and Q(2aq, aq ²) are points on x ²=4ay, and the chord PQ subtends a right angle at the vertex O.

Tags: locus

A)show that pq=-4.
This question is related to the locus however i do not know how to answer the question. Could you show the step by step process.

Comment: hint: pythagorean theorem .

Comment: Is pythagorean theorem the only way to prove pq=-4?

Answer (score 1):

HINT...the gradient of OP is $\frac{ap^2}{2ap}$ and similarly for OQ. then use $m_1.m_2=-1$ for perpendicular gradients

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen it's a **hint**. I don't need to write out a full solution, but would prefer the OP discover it for themselves rather than spoon-feed.

Comment: But hints should go as comments?

Comment: not necessarily. it is common practice on MSE to suggest what to do as answers rather than spell it out in full, so as not to spoil the aha!-moment for the OP

Comment: OK, on Cross Validated hints go as comments.